# Помогите с WinForms

Tags: winforms

Смотрите есть Combobox, точнее очень много Комбобоксов, я выбираю значение, допустим, телефон Xiaomi, и в каждый комбобокс заносится значение, там Model,Размер Памяти, оперативная ну и т.д
При выборе модели я должен очищать комбобоксы и заново вписывать туда значение, у меня стоят события на все combobox...
Собственно сам вопрос, как очищать все комбобоксы, и записывать туда значение заново, Combobox.Items.Clear() это не то, у меня смысл в том что все комбобоксы связаны, если в любом комбобоксе выбрать значение они все подстроится под него...
Clear все удаляет и до функции которая ждёт значение от комбобокса просто исчезает не успевая дойти...
Не могу понять помогите.
Вот код который заполняет комбобоксы:

```
void Con(IQueryable<MODEL> model)
        {
            foreach (var mod in model)
            {
                AddStringToCombobox(model, mod.Name);
                AddIntToCombobox(Sizememory, mod.Memory);
                AddStringToCombobox(RAM, mod.ram);
                AddStringToCombobox(Camera, mod.cam);
                AddIntToCombobox(Screen, mod.scr);
            }
        }
```

Ну собственно вот, каждый вызов комбобокса отправляет его сюда, и все комбобоксы перерисовываются...

Comment: AddStringToCombobox(Какой комбобокс, чем его заполнить).

Comment: не надо ничего чистить и перезаписывать, меняйте SelectedIndex

Comment: Да, но при выборе определенного комбобокса, такой строки может и не быть, вот в чем загвоздка...

Comment: вы же для добавляете одинаковое число элементов в каждый блок